# Count amount of inputfields with the same name in PHP?

Tags: php, input, count

I want to count the amount of inputfields with the name "termin"+number+"_von". So if there is one Inputfield with the name "termin1_von", a secound with the name "termin2_von" and third with the name "termin3_von" the code should print "123". cause there are 3 Inputs. What I want is that I can create input fields by clicking on a button and all input submission will automatically save in my MySQL database (every single submission should get an own column).

What I tried is the following:

```
<?php
    $termin_counter = 1;
    $termin_von = 'termin'.$termin_counter.'_von';

    echo $termin_counter;

    while(isset($_POST[$termin_von])){
        $termin_counter++;

        echo $termin_counter;
    }  
?>
```

this is the form

```
<form>
      <fieldset>
                <legend>Behandlungstremin</legend>
                <table id="table_output">
                <tr>
                    <th>Termin</th>
                    <th>von</th><th>bis</th>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1.</td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="termin1_von" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="time" name="termin1_bis" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="termin1_date" required=""></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <span onclick="add_termin()" name="add_termin" id="add_termin"><img src="bilder/add.png"></span>
                <span onclick="remove_termin()" name="remove_termin" id="remove_termin"><img src="bilder/close.png"></span>
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Rechnug erstellen" name="submit" id="submit">
                    </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var termin_angabe = 1;

            function add_termin() {
                termin_angabe++;
                var table = document.getElementById("table_output");
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

                cell1.innerHTML = termin_angabe + ".";
                cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="time" name="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_von" id="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_von">';
                cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="time" name="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_bis" id="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_bis">';
                cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="date" name="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_date" id="termin'+ termin_angabe+'_date">';
            }   
            function remove_termin() {
                if (termin_angabe > 1) {
                termin_angabe--;
                document.getElementById("table_output").deleteRow(-1);
                }
            }
            </script>
</form>
```

But if I run it I'm getting infinite numbers. Did I make a mistake or is there an other way of doing this?

Comment: You should use arrays instead: In html you use `name="termin_von[]"` or `name="termin_von[some_id]`, etc. and address them in php as `$_POST[$termin_von][0]`, etc. A lot easier to count and to loop over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set $termin_von only once before loop.

```
  $termin_counter = 1;
    while(true) {
      $termin_von = 'termin'.$termin_counter.'_von';
      if(!isset($_POST[$termin_von])) break;
      echo $termin_counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop here:

```
while(isset($_POST[$termin_von])){
    $termin_counter++;
    echo $termin_counter;
}
```

...will run forever for sure, because `$_POST[$termin_von]` will never be not-set, because `$termin_von` doesn't ever change. When you define this before the loop:

```
$termin_von = 'termin'.$termin_counter.'_von';
```

It's going stay as it is, a concatenated string reading `termin1_von`. It will not increment if you increment the variable `$termin_counter` later. You need to have `$termin_von` defined with the current counter number in each iteration of your loop. Move it inside the while-loop.